# Enumerating command line arguments from external script

Tags: python, sys

I have two scripts that I'm working with. The first, Script1.py, imports Script2.py and uses its `main()` by passing arguments to it in a for loop:

```
    for ipNum in ipList:
        print("Checking databases for: " + ipNum)
        Script2.main("--ip " + ipNum)
```

However, when Script1.py is ran, I get the erorr:

```
vol.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --profile=WinXPSP3x86 -f B:/vmem/zeus.vmem connscan
```

main() looks like this in Script2.py:

```
def main(args):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Is This IP Bad?')
    parser.add_argument('-i', '--ip', help='IP address to check')
    parser.add_argument('--success', help='Also display GOOD', required=False, action="store_true")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args is not None and args.ip is not None and len(args.ip) > 0:
        badip = args.ip
    else:
        my_ip = urlopen('http://icanhazip.com').read().rstrip()
```

The unrecognized arguments are, of course, the command line arguments that were entered when launchung script1. How do I appropriately enumerate through a list of single arguments to run the script2 main() multiple times?

Comment: I would move the argparse stuff out of main() and into the top level script, something like this:

Comment: There's no reason to pass data through command line arguments within a single script if you can just pass it into a function. Restructure your code so that `script1.py` can do something like `from script2 import do_stuff` and then `do_stuff('1.2.3.4', True)`.

Comment: Your argument list should be an array, not a string (just as it is in real life: the OS hands a program a *list*; generating that list from a command entered as a string at the shell is done by the shell itself).

Comment: ...when you pass a string for args, each letter of that string is parsed as a separate element (or would, if you were passing it through to `parse_args`; your current code just ignores the argument altogether).

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to have all argparse processing in the 'top level' of each .py file, where it will only be executed if that file is run as a script, rather than when its imported/called from elsehwere. Then you dont have to care about having the called script 'consuming' some of your command line arguments, and choking if it sees unexpected ones.

So each .py file that *may* be run as a script with command-line arguments looks something like this:

```
import x
import y
import argparse

def main(a, b, c):
    some code

if __name__ == '__main__':
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='a desc')
   parser.add_argument('--a') 
   parser.add_argument('--b') 
   parser.add_argument('--c') 
   args = parser.parse_args()
   main(args.a, args.b, args.c)
```

Try moving the argparse stuff out of the main() function in Script2, and call main() with regular arguments from Script1:

```
def main(ip=None, Sucess=None): 
   if ip is None: 
      ip=urlopen('http://icanhazip.com').read().rstrip()


If __name__ == '__main__':
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Is This IP Bad?')
   parser.add_argument('-i', '--ip', help='IP address to check') 
   parser.add_argument('--success', help='Also display GOOD', required=False, action="store_true")
   args = parser.parse_args()
   main(args.ip, args.success)
```

Then call from the other script with something like:

```
for ipNum in ipList: 
    print("Checking databases for: {}".format(ipNum))
    Script2.main(ipNum)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I am getting the error 'global name 'args' is not defined'

Comment: Can you paste a minimal code sample which reproduced the issue and the full error trace

Answer (score 0):

If Script2.py is only going to be called from Script1.py, the use of argparse in Script2 is over the top.  Instead, import the pertinent methods from Script2 into Script1 and use them as if they were in the same namespace (because now they are).

Script1 can use argparse to get things from the command line if need be, and pass them to Script2.  This allows for Script2 to focus on ip related behaviors, while Script1 can focus on user interaction.

```
# Script1.py
import sys, argparse
from Script2.py import *
def main()
    parser = argeparse.ArgumentParser(description="Parse arguments passed to Script1.py")
    parser.add_argument(default="None", nargs="?", dest="x", action="store", help="An optional variable named x which will default to None.")
    args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
    ip = args.x

    ipChecker(ip)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


# Script2.py
def ipChecker(self, ip):
    if ip is not None:
        my_ip = ip
    else:
        my_ip = urlopen('http://icanhazip.com').read().rstrip()
    # do stuff with my_ip

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ipChecker()
```